# Rudin Theorem 4.2 proof question

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, predicate-logic

Refering to the question [Rudin 4.2 definition of a limit of a function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2995977/rudin-4-2-definition-of-a-limit-of-a-function), I dont have enough reputation to add a comment.

I have the same question. Is'nt the proof in $\impliedby\ $ direction a logical fallacy? If $P \implies\ Q$ then all we know more is $\neg Q \implies\ \neg P$ called [modus tollens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens).

Further $\neg P\implies\ \neg Q$ is called ["Denying the antecedent, or Inverse error or Fallacy of the inverse"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denying_the_antecedent)

Isnt that what Rudin is doing here? So the proof should'nt start by assuming (4) is false, but that (5) is false.

Then from $\neg (5) \land (6) \implies\ \neg (4)$ or $ (5) \land \neg (6) \implies\ \neg (4)$ or (since logical and) $\neg (5) \land \neg (6) \implies\ \neg (4)$ hence a contradiction.

Comment: Note that $P \leftarrow Q$ is equivalent to $\lnot P \rightarrow \lnot Q$ by modus tollens.  It only becomes denying the antecedent if you assume he's trying to prove $P \rightarrow Q$ in that instant, which is where your error lies.

Comment: I've always thought that making a mistake was ok, but I have to say that if it involves thinking that Rudin might personally fall into elementary logic flaws, then I retract my vote.

Comment: @BrianMoehring agree. $ Q \to P$ implies by modus tollens $\neg P \to \neg Q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The two statements claimed to be equivalent are:

- $P$: $\lim_{x \rightarrow p}f(x) = q$
- $Q$: for every sequence $(p_n)$ in $E$ such that $p_n \neq p$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}p_n = p$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(p_n) = q$.

He shows first that $P \implies Q$ and then that $\neg P \implies \neg Q$.  The latter is equivalent to $Q \implies P$, which completes the proof that $P \iff Q$.

Comment: I was confused at first by the contrapositive of $P \implies Q$ which is $\neg P \implies \neg Q$ which happens also to be modus tollens of $Q \implies P$ which is last step in the proof. Thanks!